# Edit Button click on the row data not passing in to dropdown list React

Tags: reactjs

I am beginner at React. When I click the edit button on the table row, all the editable records are passed to the textboxes successfully. However, the dropdownlist does not. I don't know what is happening.
Here is the code I tried, attached below. Please check it and correct the error.

```
const [employeeid, setEmployeeId] = useState("select");
```

##### Form dropdownlist

```
<select
  id="employeeid"
  className="form-control"
  value={employeeid}
  onChange={(e) => setEmployeeId(e.target.value)}
>
  <option value="select">Select</option>
  {employees.map((employee) => (
    <option key={employee.employeeid} value={employee.employeeid}>
      {employee.employeename}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>;
```

##### Editbutton

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"  onClick={() => editTask(task)} >Edit</button>
```

##### Data passing into the form

```js
async function editTask(task) {
  setName(task.taskname);
  setDescription(task.description);
  setComplete(task.complete);
  setEmployeeId(task.employeeid);
  setId(task.taskid);
}
```

##### Data pass into the

```js
async function editTask(task) {
  setEmployeeId(task.employeeid);
}
```